# Trouble with executing a command in Anaconda for Python 3.6

Tags: python, git, anaconda, command

I'm trying to follow this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsHmtuXucqY for generating some text with GPT-2 and I'm having trouble with executing the command `git clone https://github.com/openai/gpt-2.git`. Anaconda gives me an error message that reads: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either your git is not installed or you need to set environment variables to make sure it is accessible outside the installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install git either using an installer or using conda:

```
conda install git
```